# Llamar procedimiento almacenado MySQL desde PYTHON

Tags: python, mysql, stored-procedure, insert, mysql-procedimiento

Estoy intentando crear un procedimiento almacenado que cargue unos valores en una tabla desde python. Para ello he hecho lo siguiente:

**El procedimiento almacenado**

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `sp_insertar` (
   IN p_n1 char(60),
   IN p_n2 varchar(60),
   IN p_n3 varchar(60),
   IN p_f  varchar(60)
)
   BEGIN
       INSERT INTO prueba (
           n1,
           n2,
           n3,
           p
       ) VALUES (
           p_n1,
           p_n2,
           p_n3,
           p_f
      );
   END
```

**Función en Python de carga de archivo**

```
def insertar(n1,n2,n3,f):

   try:
       conexion = MySQLConnection(host="localhost", user="root", passwd= "", database="prueba", auth_plugin='mysql_native_password')
       cursor = conexion.cursor()
       valores = (n1,n2,n3,f)
       cursor.callproc('sp_insertar',valores)
   except Error as e:
       print(e)
   finally:
       cursor.close()
       conexion.close()
```

Lo que me sucede al ejecutar todo el proceso es que no me carga ningún dato en la tabla. He hecho un debuger y si que he visto que la variables que contienen el dato están correctas. He podido comprobar que ha "le llega" al servidor porque en cuanto he metido por error algún valor incorrecto o he escrito mal el procedimiento me ha saltado un error de sintaxis desde el mismo servidor MySQL.

Agracezco de antemano toda la ayuda de la que me podáis ofrecer

Comment: El segundo parámetro se llama `p_nr2` pero en el insert pones `p_n2`.

Comment: Gracias @jachguate! Es que he cambiado los nombres de las variables por unos diferentes para publicarlos y me he confundido. Aún así he hecho la comparación entre ambos variables y es correcto

Comment: Hola. Supongo que los parámetros no se llaman igual que las columnas y que los tipos de cada uno coinciden con los tipos en la tabla. Otra cosa a verificar es si no estás omitiendo alguna columna que no acepta valores nulos. Verifica también que ese INSERT no esté violando alguna restricción, de llave primaria, de unique, de integridad referencial ...